# My app is not running in Android device while it's run in iPhone

Tags: firebase, flutter, android-studio, push-notification

I'm coding my add in Flutter 2.0 using Android Studio in MAC M1, and it's working fine in iPhone, but, when I try to run it in Android device I get this error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on moto g 30 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
/Users/Khalid/AndroidStudioProjects/makani/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/itdar/makani/Application.java:7: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging does not exist
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin;
                                           ^
/Users/Khalid/AndroidStudioProjects/makani/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/itdar/makani/Application.java:8: error: package io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging does not exist
import io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService;
                                           ^
/Users/Khalid/AndroidStudioProjects/makani/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/itdar/makani/Application.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.setPluginRegistrant(this);
        ^
  symbol:   variable FlutterFirebaseMessagingService
  location: class Application
/Users/Khalid/AndroidStudioProjects/makani/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/itdar/makani/Application.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
        FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
        ^
  symbol:   variable FirebaseMessagingPlugin
  location: class Application
Note: /Users/Khalid/AndroidStudioProjects/makani/android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/itdar/makani/Application.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
4 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

This is my flutter doctor:

```
Khalid@KhalidM1 makani % flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.5, on macOS 11.2.3 20D91 darwin-arm, locale en-SA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.55.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

My Flutter version is:

```
Flutter 2.0.6 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 1d9032c7e1 (3 days ago) • 2021-04-29 17:37:58 -0700
Engine • revision 05e680e202
Tools • Dart 2.12.3
```

Thanks.

Comment: It seems you havent proprly configured Firebase Messaging library for *Android*. Have you tried any tutorials for configuration specifically for android?

Comment: I did, but I didn't know what's the problem!

Comment: Have you configured the plugin registry ?

Comment: How to configured the plugin registry? Would you please give me any url to help how to do it?